# JSP: input type date

Tags: jsp

I want to use alert if users doesn't check
Date

```
<form action=“1.jsp” method=“post”>
<input type=“date” name=“day”>
```

So how Do I write in 1.jsp

I tried

```
String day = request.getparameter(“day”)
   if(day == null){
%>
   <script>
     Alert(“”)
    History.go(-1)
```

But it isn’t work
I think date’s default data is not null

Answer (score 0):

Check null and empty for input string.

```java
if(day == null || day. Length() == 0)
```